# What can be said about the smallest $N$ where $N^2 \not\equiv 1$ mod $p_x$; for all $x : 1 \leq x \leq y$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences, quadratic-residues

Choose any value for $y : y \in \mathbb{N}$

Let

$N(y)$ be the smallest natural number that satisfies the following system of quadratic congruences:

$N^2 \not\equiv 1$ mod $p_x$; for all $x : 1 \leq x \leq y$.

($p_x$ are consecutive prime numbers)

Is it true that

$N(y) \leq p_y^2$

Answer (score 1):

It's likely (although of course not proven) that there is always a twin prime pair $q, q+2$ with $p_y < q < p_y^2-1$, in which case
$N(y) \le q+1 < p_y^2$.  Conversely, all prime factors of $N(y)\pm 1$
are greater than $p_y$, so if $N(y) < p_y^2$, $N(y)\pm 1$ will be twin primes.  Thus your conjecture implies that there are infinitely many twin primes.  Don't expect to see a proof any time soon!

Empirically, $N(y)$ tends to be quite close to $p_y$.

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem is accessible by working from the fact that the natural numbers up to $p_y \times p_{y-1}$ consist of all unique values of ($N$ mod $p_{y}$, $N$ mod $p_{y-1}$)-"space". By representing this space as a cuboid, and *trimming the width*, we eradicate positions where $N^2 \equiv 1$ mod $p_y$ and we are left with another cuboid. If we trim it enough we are left with a cuboid of width $p_{y-1}$. By rotating the rows individually, we can create a cuboid whose left and right edges represent $N^2 \equiv 1$ mod $p_{y-1}$. Trim as before and repeat for all primes....

Comment: We can continue this as long as we are dealing with prime numbers $p_z : p_z>2z$. Once we reach a prime number in which that property is not true for, hopefully we can prove by exhaustion that there exists anyway, an $N: N^2 \not \equiv 1$ mod $p_i$, for all $i: 1 \leq i \leq z$ ???

Comment: As I mentioned, if you could prove your conjecture you would have proved that there are infinitely many twin primes.  This is a very famous conjecture on which many very smart people have worked very hard, and it's still out of reach.  You're not likely to succeed by elementary methods.